# struts jquery plugin anchor tag not working

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have created a page named "menubar.jsp" as shown below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

    <html>
    <head>
        <s:head/>
        <sj:head/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li><s:a action="#"><span>Home</span></s:a></li>
                    <li><s:a action="registerLink"><span>Register</span></s:a></li>

                    <s:url  id="loginClick" value="/loginLink.action"></s:url>
                    <li><sj:a id="login_click" href="%{loginClick}" targets="mainContent"><span>Login</span></sj:a></li>
                    <li><s:a action="loginLink"><span>Administration</span></s:a></li>
                    <li class='last'><s:a action="#"><span>Preferences</span></s:a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have included this page on my index.jsp page as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<title>My Air - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainPage">
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="menubar.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="ContentLeft">
                <jsp:include page="search.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>

            <div id="contentRight">
                <jsp:include page="topdeals.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i want is that, when i click the LOGIN link , the login page named loginPage.jsp should be displayed in the div with id as "mainContent".

The struts.xml file is as follows:

```
<action name="loginLink" class="com.view.LoginAction" method="loginLink">
    <result name="loginClicked">/loginPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The loginLink method in class LoginAction simply returns "loginClicked" string.
I ran the code and checked its source. Everything looks fine there but on clicking login, nothing happens. I used the same kind of code in different file. It worked fine. But here it isn't. Can anyone help me with, what i am missing or what else should i do to get it working. Thanks in advance.

The following piece of code is also trying to do the same kind of thing and it works fine. I am not able to figure out, what i am doing wrong in my 1st piece of code:

Following is my parent page loginSuccess.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainPage">

        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="menubaruser.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <div style="width:898px"><br><center>Welcome Mr. <b><s:property value="#session.name"/> </b></center> </div>
        <div id="mainContent">

           <div id="ajaxdiv">
            <div id="ContentLeft">
                <jsp:include page="search.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
            <div id="contentRight">
                <jsp:include page="topdeals.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
           </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <jsp:include page="userHistoryWidget.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>

        </div>      
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the child page menubaruser.jsp that includes some ajax calls and put the response in mainContent div of loginSuccess.jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <s:head/>
    <sj:head/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li><s:a action="#"><span>Home</span></s:a></li>
                <s:url  id="showProfile" value="/profile.action"></s:url>
                <li><sj:a id="profile_show" href="%{showProfile}" targets="mainContent"><span>Show Profile</span></sj:a></li>
                <s:url  id="editProfile" value="/editProfileLink.action"></s:url>
                <li><sj:a id="profile_edit" href="%{editProfile}" targets="mainContent"><span>Update Profile</span></sj:a></li>
                <s:url  id="signout" value="/logout.action"></s:url>
                <li><sj:a id="signout" href="%{signout}" targets="mainContent"><span>Sign Out</span></sj:a></li>
                <%-- <li class='last'><s:a action="#"><span>Contact Us</span></s:a></li> --%>
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below given is my struts.xml mapping:

```
<action name="profile" class="com.view.ProfileAction" method="showProfile">
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptorSt" />
            <result name="loginSessionNotCreated">/loginPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="profile">/profile.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="editProfileLink" class="com.view.ProfileAction" method="editProfileLink">
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptorSt" />
            <result name="loginSessionNotCreated">/loginPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="editProfile">/editProfile.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="editProfile" class="com.view.EditProfileAction" method="editProfile">
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptorSt" />
            <result name="loginSessionNotCreated">/loginPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="profileUpdated">/profileUpdated.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

This code works fine. I have implemented same things in my 1st problem. But it doesn't work. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: You are including multiple jQuery versions.

Comment: Can u help me with which one should i keep to get it working? And in my 2nd piece of code, i only changed those sj tag things, it worked fine. Wht can be the problem here?

Comment: Remove `<sj:head/>` from menubar.jsp and use it in parent page instead of including jQuery by yourself in `<script>`.

Comment: tried it @Alexsandr M. It still isn't working.. Should i put my other piece of code that works?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: I have included the second piece of code. Kindly have a look at it plz..

Comment: @AleksandrM can u suggest me anything else?? I seriously need to solve this issue..

Comment: @Andrea Ligios can u please help me with this. Its urgent..